# OSError: [Errno 27] File too large

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code:

```
N=int(input())
a=0
b=1
print(a,end=" ")
print(b,end=" ")
while(1):
    c=a+b
    if (c==N):
        print(c)
        break
    else:
        print(c,end=" ")
        a,b=b,(a+b)
```

But the following error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Main.py", line 12, in
    print(c,end=" ")
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large
Command exited with non-zero status (1)
```

I am new at python. What is the problem..?? And how do i solve this problem...??

Comment: that is really a strange error at this point. Try to write ```print(c,end=" ",file=sys.stdout)``` does that fix your problem?

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you running some sort of partition on your computer?

Comment: @Barmar `a,b=b,(a+b)` is assignment with unpacking.  It should change both `a` and `b`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks. I misparsed it as `(a), (b=b), (a+b)` rather than `(a, b) = (b, (a+b))`

Comment: So this program is calculating the Fibonacci series. If `N` isn't in the series, it will loop forever.

Comment: The series starts `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8`. If you enter `4` it will never stop and eventually fill up the output file.

Comment: @Barmar Xactly...!!But How can I solve this error../??

Comment: @Diana Not working

Comment: @Rakibul What is the program supposed to do if you enter a number that isn't in the series?

Comment: If you think about that question, I expect that the change you need to make will become obvious.

Comment: hmm. maybe change your condition to ```c > N``` then it convergences if you reach that number

Answer (score 0):

Replace the condition in the while loop. You have given a condition such it executes infinite times. Try giving a valid condition.

Comment: `while (a+b<=N):` for example.  Or for that matter, just make the break clause check `if  (c >= N)`